# Relational data with modifications/variants

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, merge, relational-database, database-versioning

Let's say a supermarket has one table with statistical revenue data by business day. In a second table they want to try out different variations of these data, f.e. less bakery revenue at 1st January, one more public holiday or maybe opening on sundays.

I do not want to duplicate the whole revenue data of a year or more for just a few variations. Additionally it should be easily possible to show the diff between the base table and one alternative scenario.

To make it a little more clear, I created a demo case at SQLFiddle. `SUPERMARKET_DAYS` is the table with the base revenue data. `ALTERNATIVES` are the variations/alternatives or scenarios (however you want to name it) and `ALTERNATIVE_DAYS` is a table with a similar structure as the first one and holds the concrete changes.

[Example at SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/31349)

```
SUPERMARKET_DAYS 
(
    ID,
    DAY,
    NUM_CUSTOMERS,
    NUM_VISITORS,
    REVENUE_BAKERY,
    REVENUE_BEVERAGE,
    REVENUE_CANNED,
    REVENUE_DAIRY,
    REVENUE_DRY,
    REVENUE_FROZEN,
    REVENUE_MEAT,
    REVENUE_CLEAN,
    REVENUE_PERSONAL_CARE,
    REVENUE_PAPER,
    REVENUE_OTHER
)

ALTERNATIVES
(
    ID,
    TITLE
)

ALTERNATIVE_DAYS 
(
    ID,
    DAY,
    NUM_CUSTOMERS,
    NUM_VISITORS,
    REVENUE_BAKERY,
    REVENUE_BEVERAGE,
    REVENUE_CANNED,
    REVENUE_DAIRY,
    REVENUE_DRY,
    REVENUE_FROZEN,
    REVENUE_MEAT,
    REVENUE_CLEAN,
    REVENUE_PERSONAL_CARE,
    REVENUE_PAPER,
    REVENUE_OTHER
)
```

I do not even know, if this schema design makes any sense but it illustrates the problem.

- How would you store this kind of data?
- I thought about something like a versioning table but this does not really solve my problem.
- I could merge both tables inside of my java code.
- Is there something like the `MERGE` functionality for views?

I would really be grateful for every kind of idea or the correct keyword for my own investigations. This problem should already exist but I didn't find much to solve it, so I maybe did not search with the correct terms.

Thank you everybody!